# ObjectMapper null value serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization

I've created a side app to test seriliazation of `Map<String,Object>` by ObjectMapper.

In general I want to get flat 1 level json using
`mapper.writeValueAsString(map)`.

My base object is a map with those values

```
"name":bob",
"color" : null
```

My side app produces great string

```
{
   "name": "bob",
   "color" : null
}
```

But when I use the same code in my webapp I get the following **ugly** json string:

```
{
   "name": "bob",
   "color" : {
              "valueType": "NULL"
           }
}
```

I'm using the following maven dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong? Note that I don't want to ignore null values...

Comment: and which appserver do you use to run your webapp?

Comment: 1. Could you confirm you're using the sam Jackson version in your app and on an appserver? It could be that your dependency is evicted if appserver has a dependency on a later version. 2. Your Jackson version is really old, it's 2.6 these days,any reasons not to use that? Also, your 1.0.4 version is likely evicted by v 2.3.3 because databind depends on it. 3. Is there a good reason why do you care how your Json looks like?

Comment: @Tim - yo were right... I was wrong with the versions I posted. I'm using Jackson version 2.3.3 (but I will check 2.6). The 1.0.4 relates to glassfish json. I'm saving dynamic json objects in a noSQL DB (Elastic) so I want to keep it simple (null is better then JsonValue:null).